# Android - Customize the Action Bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, customization

I need to customize my Action Bar by changing color, substitute the default icons (settings and the "back" arrow) with custom images, and remove the Action Bar title with a custom font placed at the center of the Action Bar.

How can I apply these changes?

I already tried to change the background color of the Action Bar but it doesn't work, can you tell me why please?

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/aBbG</item>
</style>

<style name="aBbG" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">#b10600</item>
</style>
```

Very thanks in advance!

Comment: Bear in mind that Google publicly mocks developers who use centered titles on the action bar (e.g., http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pEGWcMTxs3I, around the 14:00 mark).

Comment: I suggest a way to you below , you can do like that( it is just one way I think)

Answer (score 0):

### I suggest you this way :

I suggest a way to you below , you can do like that( it is just one way I think)

- Hide your actionbar. like this : `actionBar.hide();`
- then create `linearlayout` and put it in your main `activty` which calls your `fragments`
- then you can customize your layout as you needs.

I do it as I said. You can see the screenshot below:(it is not actionbar it is linearlayout)

[image]

Comment: Mmm, very clever thanks, I will surely try!
However is there no way to maintain the Action Bar and make it look like this?